# where to find all the "options" available on spark.read api on Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val df = spark.read    
              .format("json")
              .option("inferSchema=true")
              .option("multiline=true")
              .load("/file/to/something.json")
```

I would like to know all the options available on this `spark.read` API in Spark 2.3.0

Where to find these details? I've tried searching in Spark documentation but I was unable to find that.

EDIT:
 [Where is the reference for options for writing or reading per format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365042/where-is-the-reference-for-options-for-writing-or-reading-per-format)
this does not have the list of all the available option for the "spark.read" API, i am not interested in spark.write api.

Comment: I am looking for all the hardcoded "option" values which is available on the spark.read.option(...) api

Comment: You need to be creative and try things, that's how I did it.