# check whether is spark format exists or not

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sparkcore, spark-redshift

### Context

Spark reader has the function `format`, which is used to specify a data source type, for example, `JSON`, `CSV` or third party `com.databricks.spark.redshift`

### Help

how can I check whether a third-party format exists or not, let me give a case

- In local spark, connect to redshift two open source libs available 1. `com.databricks.spark.redshift` 2. `io.github.spark_redshift_community.spark.redshift`, how I can determine which libs the user pastes in the classpath

### What I tried

- Class.forName("com.databricks.spark.redshift"), not worked
- I tried to check spark code for how they are throwing error, here is [line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.1.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala#L690), but unfortunately Utils is not available publically
- Instead of targeting format option, I tried to target JAR file `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`
- `spark.read.format("..").load()` in try/catch

I looking for a proper & reliable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44302878/5751473) answer help you.

To only check whether is spark format exists or not,

> spark.read.format("..").load() in try/catch

is enough.

And as all data sources usually register themselves using `DataSourceRegister` interface (and use shortName to provide their alias):

You can use Java's `ServiceLoader.load` method to find all registered implementations of `DataSourceRegister` interface.

```scala
import java.util.ServiceLoader
import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister

val formats = ServiceLoader.load(classOf[DataSourceRegister])

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
formats.asScala.map(_.shortName).foreach(println)
```

Comment: out-of-the-box solution, seems expert solution, thanks @Se ven